# javascript find all the object in an array and convert it into an array to array

Tags: javascript

I have a list of array with object in it like address and details

#### Input

```
var arr = [
    {id: 1, name: "abc", address: {street: "some text1", pin: 879888, state: "my-state1"}, details: {section: "A", roll: 12, branch:"CSE"}},
    {id: 2, name: "xyz", address: {street: "some text2", pin: 879887, state: "my-state2"}, details: {section: "B", roll: 13, branch:"IT"}}
]
```

I want to iterate on this array and convert all the inner object so that it will look something like below

### Expected Result

```
var arr = [
    {id: 1, name: "abc", street: "some text1", pin: 879888, state: "my-state1", section: "A", roll: 12, branch: "CSE"},
    {id: 2, name: "xyz", street: "some text2", pin: 879887, state: "my-state2", section: "B", roll: 13, branch: "IT"}
]
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

use `map` and spread operator will simplify.

Alternatively, you can do generic way with out hard coding keys.

```js
var arr = [
  {
    id: 1,
    name: "abc",
    address: { street: "some text1", pin: 879888, state: "my-state1" },
    details: { section: "A", roll: 12, branch: "CSE" }
  },
  {
    id: 2,
    name: "xyz",
    address: { street: "some text2", pin: 879887, state: "my-state2" },
    details: { section: "B", roll: 13, branch: "IT" }
  }
];

const updated = arr.map(item => ({
  id: item.id,
  name: item.name,
  ...item.address,
  ...item.details
}));

const updatedGeneric = arr.map(item => {
  let res = {};
  Object.entries(item).forEach(([key, value]) => Object.assign(res, typeof value === "object" ? value : { [key]: value }));
  return res;
});

console.log(updated);
console.log(updatedGeneric);
```

Comment: I think this is the best solution

Comment: thank you @siva. Appreciate your quick response

Answer (score 1):

In this case, the loop processes the entire array and check if prop is not an object then copy key\value in a new object. If prop is an object just merge this object to new object. then you should return a new object.

```js
var arr = [
    {id: 1, name: "abc", address: {street: "some text1", pin: 879888, state: "my-state1"}, details: {section: "A", roll: 12, branch:"CSE"}},
    {id: 2, name: "xyz", address: {street: "some text2", pin: 879887, state: "my-state2"}, details: {section: "B", roll: 13, branch:"IT"}}
]

let res = arr.map(row => {
   let newRow = {};
   for (let key in row) {
     if (row.hasOwnProperty(key)) {
        if (typeof row[key] !== 'object') {
          newRow[key] = row[key];
        } else {
          newRow = {
            ...newRow,
            ...row[key]
          }
        }
     }
   }
   return newRow;
});

console.info(res);
```

Comment: You should explain your answer and not just post a solution ^^. That's not how it works

Comment: Yeah, added small description :)

Answer (score 0):

I think your goal is to flatten the objects in the array. So to achieve this, you could iterate over the object extract the values which are objects, and then spread them into the object. It could look like this:

```
var arr = [
    { id: 1, name: "abc", address: { street: "some text1", pin: 879888, state: "my-state1" }, details: { section: "A", roll: 12, branch: "CSE" } },
    { id: 2, name: "xyz", address: { street: "some text2", pin: 879887, state: "my-state2" }, details: { section: "B", roll: 13, branch: "IT" } }
]

const newArray = arr.map(obj => {
    const newObject = obj
    for(let key in newObject) {
        if(typeof newObject[key] === "object") {
            newObject = {
                ...newObject,
                ...newObject[key]
            }
            delete newObject[key]
        }
    }
    return newObject
})
```

Answer (score 0):

You can iterate over the array using [Array.map](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map), destructure `address`, `details` and combine the rest of the properties into a new object using [destructuring assignment](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Destructuring_assignment).

Then merge every object into a single object using [Object.assign()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/assign)

```js
const result = arr.map(({ address, details, ...rest }) =>
  Object.assign(rest, address, details));
```